# C++ code to sort a list of elements

Tags: c++, mergesort

This is a code uses mergesort algorithm to sort a list of elements.What are the possible improvements on the code?Also are there any unhealthy coding practice involved in this code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<random>
#include<chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
vector<int> merge(vector<int> a,vector<int> b){
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    vector<int> result;
    while(i<a.size()&&j<b.size()){
        if(a[i]<b[j]){
            result.push_back(a[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else{
            result.push_back(b[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    while(i<a.size()){
        result.push_back(a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    while(j<b.size()){
        result.push_back(b[j]);
        j++;
    }
    return result;
}

vector<int> mergesort(vector<int> a,int low,int hi){
    vector<int> b,c,result;
    if(low==hi)
        return {a[hi]};
    b=mergesort(a,low,(low+hi)/2);
    c=mergesort(a,(hi+low)/2+1,hi);
    result=merge(b,c);
    return result;
}
int main(){

    std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    std::mt19937 eng(rd()); // seed the generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0,90); // define the range
    vector <int> num;
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
        num.push_back(distr(eng));    
    vector<int> a=mergesort(num,0,num.size()-1);
    for(auto &i:a)
        cout<<i<<" ";  
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<random>
#include<chrono>
```

Leave some space between the `#include`s and the rest of your code, that's easier to read. Besides, I really like `<chrono>` myself too, but you don't seem to use it afterwards.

```
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
```

`using` directives for a whole namespace is a bad idea. You risk conflicts between the names defined in `std` (and there's quite a lot of them) and those you define yourself. Safety is worth a few more keystrokes.

```
vector<int> merge(vector<int> a,vector<int> b){
```

That function signature means you're passing `a` and `b` by value, that is to say you copy the argument vectors. It might be the good move sometimes, but here it isn't, because you only read them. So `const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b` is better.

```
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
```

`i`, `j`, why not? but it doesn't scream what you'll be using those variables for.

```
    vector<int> result;
    while(i<a.size()&&j<b.size()){
```

I would rather use iterators in the first place (I mean, in the function's signature), because:

- it avoids comparison issues (`vector.size()` is unsigned, whereas `i` and `j` are signed)
- it makes it easier to write and use generic code
- it allows you to merge sequences which are only a part of a container, or even inside the same container.

  ```
  if(a[i]<b[j]){
  ```

There's a trick here: if `a[i]` == `b[j]` you'll insert `b[j]` first. It might be innocuous -it is for an `int`- but programmers expect that `min(a, b)` will return `a` if `a == b`. Since a sorting algorithm is a good candidate for abstraction (a vector of strings is sorted the same way as a vector of ints or floats), you should respect that rule.

```
        result.push_back(a[i]);
        i++;
```

Unless you need to keep track of the old value, use pre-incrementation (`++i`) since `i++` creates and returns a temporary value.

```
        }
        else{
            result.push_back(b[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    while(i<a.size()){
        result.push_back(a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    while(j<b.size()){
        result.push_back(b[j]);
        j++;
    }
```

copy and paste is an anti-pattern. Standard algorithms will provide what you need in a more elegant way, especially if you use iterators: `std::copy(current_a, a.end(), std::back_inserter(result));`

```
    return result;
}

vector<int> mergesort(vector<int> a,int low,int hi){
    vector<int> b,c,result;
    if(low==hi)
        return {a[hi]};
    b=mergesort(a,low,(low+hi)/2);
    c=mergesort(a,(hi+low)/2+1,hi);
    result=merge(b,c);
    return result;
}
```

This part is all right, even if I believe you should try to reduce the place you need to merge-sort or at least the number of allocations.

```
int main(){

    std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    std::mt19937 eng(rd()); // seed the generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0,90); // define the range
    vector <int> num;
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
        num.push_back(distr(eng));    
    vector<int> a=mergesort(num,0,num.size()-1);
    for(auto &i:a)
```

You generally don't take integers by reference (a reference is the size of or bigger than an `int`, and you don't take non-const references when you don't modify the variable, which you don't.

```
        cout<<i<<" ";  
}
```

Comment: Great answer. One other tip I'd recommend is to reserve space for the result vector, since we know exactly how big it will need to be. `result.reserve(a.size() + b.size());`

Comment: @FredLarson: I used to think so too, but then I read Bjarne Stroustrup C++ FAQ: "People sometimes worry about the cost of std::vector growing incrementally. I used to worry about that and used reserve() to optimize the growth. After measuring my code and repeatedly having trouble finding the performance benefits of reserve() in real programs, I stopped using it except where it is needed to avoid iterator invalidation (a rare case in my code). Again: measure before you optimize."

Comment: Interesting. Looks like I'll have to do some experiments of my own.

Comment: Thank you so much.Got to learn so much from this answer.Btw i used chrono to get the execution time but forgot to remove it while pasting here.Once again thanks a lot! @papagaga

Comment: I made a version of this code that sorts strings instead of integers. Using `reserve` does seem to produce a measurable difference. Feeding it some 300,000 strings, it seems to save about 50ms -- around 160ms vs. 210ms. 50ms doesn't sound like much, but that's over 20%!

Answer (score 5):

The functions should be templatized so that they can sort any kind of comparable values.

You have made the two classic mistakes in mergesort:

- **Unstable sorting.**

  > ```
  > if(a[i]<b[j]){
  >     result.push_back(a[i]);
  >     i++;
  > }
  > else{
  >     result.push_back(b[j]);
  >     j++;
  > }
  > ```

  One of the useful properties of mergesort is that it is a [stable sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). To achieve that, though, when two `a[i]` and `b[j]` are equal, you have to prefer to take the item from `a` first, because `a` was originally to the left of `b`. Therefore, use `<=` for that comparison.

  Of course, stability doesn't matter when sorting integers. But you might as well write it correctly so that it also works for sorting arbitrary objects.
- **Overflow.**

  > ```
  > b=mergesort(a,low,(low+hi)/2);
  > c=mergesort(a,(hi+low)/2+1,hi);
  > ```

  `low+high` is vulnerable to integer overflow.  The better technique would be `low + (high - low) / 2`.

Answer (score 3):

Merge Sort is a great choice when the data don't fit into working memory.  However, our inputs and outputs are all in memory, so we're better off using a more suitable algorithm, such as Quicksort.

Luckily, the C++ Standard Library provides `std::sort()`, which is intended to be a good choice when inputs fit into memory (it's the implementer's choice of algorithm, not necessarily Quicksort).  A good implementation won't require such a large memory overhead as the hand-written sort (we need space for the entire input *and* output during the sort - i.e. twice that of the elements, leading to an increased risk of `std::bad_alloc`; most `std::sort()` require little or no extra memory during operation).

Summary: use `std::sort()` and save your brainpower for other challenges.

Comment: Do you mind adding a little more detail about why merge sort is good when it doesn't fit in working memory and why quicksort (or `std::sort`) is more suitable when it does?

Comment: @Danno, almost any textbook will explain that; I don't think I could do as good a job.  If you want to know more, you could even [start with Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Comparison_with_other_sort_algorithms).